# Keep consistent submit button styling between firefox and safari?

Tags: css, firefox, safari, cross-browser

So I have a submit button that is styled with the following css:

```
#search_submit {
    width:150px;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
```

In safari it look like this:
[image]

In firefox it looks like this:
[image]

I would like to get the font to display at `1.5em` as it does in firefox, but I would like to maintain the rounded corners that are present in safari (which disappear in firefox, only when I add the `font-size:1.5em`

I read somewhere that its better to use `em` for cross browser support? is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Using `em` for font-size is not necessarily 'better' for cross browser support.  It's recommended because of its scalable nature, but it may not always have the consistency of using pixels (pixel perfect as they say...)

It generally isn't that difficult to get the buttons to look the same between firefox and safari.  Without a link to see the page it's hard to say why yours are so different and my guess is you have other css styles on the page effecting your buttons.